# SQL Server Express IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-express

I just want to ask what's the proper way to use `IF` statement in SQL Server 2014 Express? I have this code but no luck it is not working.

```
select 
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    if(field5 = 'value1', field5,
    if(field5 = 'value2', field5,
    if(field5 = 'value3', field5,
    if(field5 = 'value4', field5, field6)))) 
from 
    table1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you need [`iif()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) function and not `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

the standard `SQL` syntax for `IF` is [`CASE WHEN THEN END`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Conditional_.28CASE.29_expressions), for example:

```
SELECT field1,
  CASE field5 
    WHEN 'value1' THEN field5 
    WHEN 'value2' THEN field4
    ELSE field3
  END
FROM table1
```

Or

```
SELECT field1,
  CASE WHEN field5='value1' THEN field5 ELSE field4 END
FROM table1
```

The `ELSE` part is optional..

Comment: Thanks @Kokizzu and simo.379209 for the immediate response, both your suggestion works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, deleted my comment because I thought I'd syntaxed it wrong.  Anyway now I am more confident.  @Cleyventh has 4 fields that all return field5, so you can use `CASE WHEN field5 in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4') THEN field5 ELSE field6 END`

Comment: @simo.379209 does CASE WHEN statement can be nested. For example CASE WHEN within CASE WHEN statement. Thanks!